# Difference between for/while loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

This function should return a value of 2 instead of 3.
It works fine with a while loop but I would like to know why it’s not working with this for loop which looks pretty similar to me.

```
def count_words(string, word):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i:i+len(word)] == word:
            count +=1
            print("count",i)
            i += len(word)
        else:
            i += 1
    return count
print(count_words("AAAA","AA"))
```

Comment: show us the version with the `while` loop, please

Comment: A for-loop isn't suitable here because "i" is overwritten at each iteration start without respecting its previous value.

Comment: @Cid literally just replace for with a while and it works fine.

Comment: @Dodokh Id you mean the other version does `while i in range(len(string))`, then that will not do what you expect (I suspect).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It returns a value of 2 which is correct.

Comment: `range(len(string))` for the example string of `'AAAA'` essentially gives you the equivalent to the sequence `[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]`. With the `while` loop you check if `0 in [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]` is `True`, and if `2 in [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]` is `True`, and if `4 in [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]` is `True`. Is that what you intended with the `while` loop? It might give you the correct result, but does it do it in the way you wanted and expected?

Comment: The goal is to count the iteration of `word` in the `string`. In this example it should count 2 because I don't want it to overlap. So `i` increase 2 (the length of word) only when it matches, otherwise `i` increases only 1 as stated in the `else`. Maybe `while i < len(string)` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change i inside the loop, this will fix your code:

```
def count_words(string, word):
    j = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[j:j+len(word)] == word:
            count +=1
            print("count",j)
            j += len(word)
        else:
            j += 1
    return count
print(count_words("AAAA","AA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `for` loop will *always* iterate over `0`, `1`, ... until `len(string) - 1`. The assignments you make to `i` inside the loop are discarded.

The problem is that [`range(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) creates an *object* which will yield a new value which is assigned to `i` each iteration of the loop. The assignment you make to `i` inside the loop doesn't change the sequence returned by the range object.